# R:summarise +group_by function produces no result

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to collapse the column b so that entries in column a will have only one row and column B will be multiple values separated by ;
my code is:(my file is known as disease)

```
a       b
2012    cancer
2013    HIV
2014    cancer
2014    HIV

library(dplyr)
summary <- disease %>% 
   group_by(a) %>%
   summarise(b = paste0(b, collapse = ';')) %>% 
   ungroup()
```

This does not give me any error but does not yield the desired results too. Summary file is generated but has only one column named b and that is empty.

Comment: Presumably dplyr is loaded?

Comment: Works for me (two columns in output)

Comment: @Bioinformatician so post actual data...

Comment: Please provide an example that reproduces the issue.  (You could try running on a subset of your file to see if you can reproduce the issue without the full file.)

Comment: probably `plyr` is loaded, `detach("packages:plyr")`, or `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thank you so so much..dplyr::summarise worked!!!